# How to scale y-Axis in d3.js according to data input correctly

Tags: javascript, django, d3.js

I created a small Barchart. My problem is that the y-axis doesn't scale according to my dataset. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Graph]

So as you can see the 313 is a little bit above the 800 scale. I would like the 300 to be at the 300. I tweaked with the scalings but I just end up messing it up completely. I am very new to D3.js so I hope someone can help.

Here is my code:

```
var svgWidth = 1000, svgHeight = 800;
var barWidth = svgWidth / month_description.length;
var barPadding = 5;

var svg = d3.select('svg')
.attr("width", svgWidth)
.attr("height", svgHeight);

var barChart = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d) {
         return svgHeight - d - 20
    })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i + 10;
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d;
    })
    .attr("width", barWidth - barPadding)
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        var translate = [barWidth * i, 0];
        return "translate("+ translate +")";
    });

var text = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return svgHeight - 20;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return barWidth * i + 35;
    })
    .attr("fill", "white");

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(month_description)])
    .range([0, svgWidth]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([svgHeight, 0]);

var x_axis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale);

var y_axis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(yScale);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(50, 10)")
    .call(y_axis);

var xAxisTranslate = svgHeight - 20;

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(50, " + xAxisTranslate  +")")
    .call(x_axis);
```

Help is very much appreciated. Thanks very much in advance!!

Comment: you do not apply yscale when drawing rectangles; eg the y should probably be `function(d) { return yScale(d); }`, while height `function(d) { return yScale(0) - yScale(d); }`

Comment: Thanks so much Coderino. I will try this tomorrow and will let you know how it goes. If you convert it into an answer I can upvote you and accept your answer.

Comment: It worked! perfectly!! Thanks again!!